# How do I get the entity that represents the current user in Symfony?

Tags: entity-framework, security, symfony

I am using the Symfony security setup. Everything works fine, but I don't know how to do one important thing:

In twig, I can reach the current user's info by doing:

```
Welcome, {{ app.user.username }}
```

or similar

How do I access this same information in the Controller? Specifically, I want to get the current user entity so I can store it relationally in another entity (one-to-one mapping).

I was really hoping it'd be

```
$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()
```

but that doesn't work. It gives me a class of type

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User
```

and I want one of type

```
Acme\AuctionBundle\Entity\User
```

which is my entity....

Comment: [The Symfony Book: Retrieving the user object](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object)

Answer (score 248, accepted):

## Symfony 4+, 2019+ Approach

In symfony 4 (probably 3.3 also, but only real-tested in 4) you can inject the `Security` service via ***auto-wiring*** in the controller like this:

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class SomeClass
{
    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
       $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function privatePage() : Response
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser(); // null or UserInterface, if logged in
        // ... do whatever you want with $user
    }
}
```

---

### Symfony 2- Approach

As @ktolis says, you first have to configure your `/app/config/security.yml`.

Then with

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
$user->getUsername();
```

should be enougth!

`$user` is your User Object! You don't need to query it again.

Find out the way to set up your providers in `security.yml` from [Sf2 Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers) and try again.

Best luck!

Comment: What if i need the user entity on a PHP template?

Comment: @DomingoSL Check the following link from the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object

Comment: Since Symfony 2.6, the security.context service has been deprecated and split into two new services: security.authorization_checker and security.token_storage. You can check the correct way to fetch current user here : http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

Comment: I'm on Symfony 5.1.2 and on `$user = $this->security->getUser();`, `$user` is always `null` for me, whether logged in or not.

Comment: Oh seems like it's because I'm doing this in an Event Subscriber, and this is not yet initialized this early in the request.

Comment: is this $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser(); a sure fire? because I have the problem with $currentUser = $this->getUser();, where sometimes $currentUser is null :(

Comment: @NickRolando Please how did you resolve this issue on Symfony 5? I'm also using Event Subscriber and still getting null whether logged in or not.

Comment: @jafojial Try using an Event Listener instead `onKernelRequest` . Since a single page may make several requests, I checked `if(!$event->isMasterRequest()) { return; }` first.

Answer (score 69):

## Best practice

According to [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object) since Symfony 2.1 simply use this shortcut :

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

The above is **still working on Symfony 3.2** and is a shortcut for this :

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

> The `security.token_storage` service was introduced in Symfony 2.6. Prior to Symfony 2.6, you had to use the `getToken()` method of the `security.context` service.

**Example** : And if you want directly the username :

```
$username = $this->getUser()->getUsername();
```

## If wrong user class type

The user will be an object and the class of that object will depend on your [user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#security-user-providers%22Configuring%20how%20Users%20are%20Loaded%22).

Answer (score 7):

In Symfony version >= 5 and PHP >= 8.0 you can type hint the authenticated user using Attributes, only in controllers though:

```php
public function indexAction(#[CurrentUser] User $user): Response
{
     // do something
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working starting from Symfony 6.2 if one drops FrameworkExtraBundle: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40333

Answer (score 6):

The thread is a bit old but i think this could probably save someone's time ...

I ran into the same problem as the original question, that the type is showed as
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User

It eventually turned out that i was logged in using an in memory user

my security.yml looks something like this

```
security:
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, fos_userbundle]
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN' ] }
```

the in_memory user type is always Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User if you want to use your own entity, log in using that provider's user.

Thanks,
hj

Answer (score 6):

In symfony >= 3.2, [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html) states that:

> An alternative way to get the current user in a controller is to
>   type-hint the controller argument with [UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface/UserInterface.html) (and default it
>   to null if being logged-in is optional):
>
> ```
> use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface\UserInterface;
>
> public function indexAction(UserInterface $user = null)
> {
>     // $user is null when not logged-in or anon.
> }
> ```
>
> This is only recommended for experienced developers who don't extend
>   from the [Symfony base controller](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller.html#the-base-controller-class-services) and don't use the [ControllerTrait](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.html)
>   either. Otherwise, it's recommended to keep using the getUser()
>   shortcut.

[Blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-user-value-resolver-for-controllers) about it

Comment: This helped me a lot while trying to get current user in an EventSubscriber: i had to autowire (Security $security) as param in __construct then use $security->getUser() and voilà!

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please explain about answer. stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -39):

Well, first you need to request the username of the user from the session in your controller action like this:

```
$username=$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUserName();
```

then do a query to the db and get your object with regular dql like

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');    
"SELECT u FROM Acme\AuctionBundle\Entity\User u where u.username=".$username;
$q=$em->createQuery($query);
$user=$q->getResult();
```

the $user should now hold the user with this username ( you could also use other fields of course)

...but you will have to first configure your /app/config/security.yml configuration to use the appropriate field for your security provider like so:

```
security:
 provider:
  example:
   entity: {class Acme\AuctionBundle\Entity\User, property: username}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Well Martin you either want the user OR the username. The choice is yours. It's your responsibility to get the object you need. And as you said you don't want the regular user but the Acme namespace user.

Comment: "SELECT u FROM Acme\AuctionBundle\Entity\User u where u.username=".$username; = YOU SHOULD USE PARAMETRIZED QUERIES!

Comment: `$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()` itself gets you the logged in user object. You don't have to query it back again. In fact, which version were you using ?