# How can I get the name of the user logged into the PC in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm doing an internship and my task is to implement single sign-on into an existing Symfony2 project with Twig templating. 
More info about the single sign-on: I have to get the name of the user logged into the PC. Based on that name, I have to do other things.

I just discovered this [bundle](https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md), but I don't know if it fits my situation.

At this moment, I am pretty new to Symfony2 and its habits. I have never done a task like this so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: refer this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7682827/3164682

Comment: That one is to get the user logged into the application and not into the PC, or am I wrong?

Comment: You can't - how could you get environment variables from the client side?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Windows Domain, you can use Kerberos in order to retrieve the windows username.

See http://www.grolmsnet.de/kerbtut/ for more details.

In PHP, $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"] will give you the windows username.

Symfony 2.6 is able to use this variable for authentification (http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements)