# How to find the current user in the repository?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am looking for if it is possible to find the current user in a repository and if yes, how?

Comment: do you mean ... injecting `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security` in the constructor and calling its `getUser` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the entity that represents the current user in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680917/how-do-i-get-the-entity-that-represents-the-current-user-in-symfony2)

Comment: @Jakumi
that's the idea, I tried that, but it did not work

Comment: @Jeroen this exemple is in a controller, I wan't do it in a repository

Comment: "it did not work", care to elaborate with code and error message or something? because it is the correct approach, and it should definitely work

Comment: @delph49 The answers also show how to do it in a service, your repository is a service so you can apply those solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your repository, edit your `__construct`, adding `Security $security`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

/**
 * @var Security
 */
private $security;

public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry, Security $security)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Entityname::class);
        $this->security = $security;
    }
```

then call getUser():

```
public function something(){
    $this->security->getUser()
}
```

Comment: Thanks to the response, but with this I have this error:Argument 1 passed to App\Core\Repository\HospitalisationRepository::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in /home/docker/symfony/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Repository/ContainerRepositoryFactory.php on line 84

Comment: That's weird. Can you post your code? And what is your Symfony version?

Comment: it's ok, I did differently. Thanks