# Symfony get current User entity in controller

Tags: symfony, user-interface, symfony6

I'm beginner in Symfony (6.1) and sometimes I need to get the current User in my controllers.

The way I use for the moment is :

```
$user = $userRepository->find($this->getUser()->getId());
```

But they are a better way ?

Because `$this->getUser()` give me the UserInterface and I need the User entity. [screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGj4Q.png)

Thanks to read me

Comment: There may be a basic misunderstanding here.  getUser does indeed return your actual user object.  dd($user) will confirm the class is App\Entity\User or whatever you acual user class is.  Your IDE only knows that is it a UserInterface.  You just need to tell your IDE using var annotation what the actual class is and then the IDE will show you the complete class.

Comment: "because $this->getUser() give me the UserInterface" - what do you mean by that? Is there any actual difference between the "UserInterface" and the "User entity"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the entity that represents the current user in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680917/how-do-i-get-the-entity-that-represents-the-current-user-in-symfony)

Answer (score 3):

Using `$this->getUser()` will get you the current user (that implements UserInterface). The `getUser()` method lives in **AbstractController.php** that is part of the Symfony FrameworkBundle. You could extend this controller if you really want to change the `getUser()` method to not use the UserInterface, but I think it would be better to simply change the typehint of the function (setUser) you call (in your screenshot -please write this out next time-) to use the UserInterface. Something like this:

```
public function setUser(UserInterface $user) 
{
    //....
}
```

**Edit:**
After consideration, thanks to Cerad's valid point below, it is probably best to use `setUser(User $user)` given that you might use another class that implements UserInterface. Then either use var annations to tell your IDE which class you use, like so:

```
/** @var User $user */
$user = $this->getUser();
```

Or extend AbstractController so that it has a getUser method with a User return type like so:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class BaseController extends AbstractController
{
    protected function getUser(): ?User
    {
        if (!$this->container->has('security.token_storage')) {
            throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application. Try running "composer require symfony/security-bundle".');
        }

        if (null === $token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()) {
            return null;
        }

        return $token->getUser();
    }
}
```

or maybe even better, like this:

```
/**
 * @return User|null
 */
protected function getUser(): ?UserInterface
{
    return parent::getUser();
}
```

Comment: To add to your answer I think it would be more future proof to typehint it as `UserInterface|User` (syntax supported since PHP 8.0) because it is very likely that setUser will be called somewhere else in the code using an actual `User`

Comment: The assumption though is that consumers of the user need access to whatever additional methods are defined on the application specific user.  I don't know why you would not just typehint the results of getUser so the IDE knows what class is being returned. `/** @var User */
        $user = $this->getUser();` and be done with it.  Basically with `UserInterface|User` you are telling people that it is okay to just pass an UserInterface which is probably not the case.

Comment: @Cerad That's a fair point but at the same time I think it's implicitly saying that the setter expects a class that implements UserInterface, which is the case (why would you ever pass an actual interface to a setter?). Yes, annotations work just as fine and are 100% explicit but after using both for a while I do think typehinting the setter is a lot more practical.

Comment: @hugoschweitzer Well no.  Just no.  The setter expects a User class not an UserInterface.  Passing a non-User class that happens to also implement UserInterface could easily cause it to blow up.

Comment: @Cerad, it does make sense what you are describing. There is a chance another class may be passed that will cause problems, although changes usually aren't great you have multiple classes implementing UserInterface you are right.

Comment: @Cerad I think I understand better what you mean now, I've never encountered a case where I'd need multiple classes to implement `UserInterface` so it didn't really occur to me that it wasn't a good idea. On top of that having to annotate `$this->getUser()` always felt out of place to me (especially with Symfony 6/PHP 8) but I guess there's no way around it.

Comment: Your last example should be `protected function getUser(): ?User`

Comment: That unfortunately will cause issues as well with an IDE like PHPStorn

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit puzzled by some of the other answers so it might be that I am the one who is confused.  The basic problem is that getUser is typehinted to return an UserInterface but the actual User object is needed.  My solution is to explicitly tell the IDE what getUser is actually returning:

```
use App\Entity\User; # or whetever the application defined user is

class MyController extends AbstractController 
{
    public function someMethod() 
    {
        /** @var User */
        $user = $this->getUser();
```

And everyone, especially the IDE, is happy.

Once again you need to do what is basically a typecast because the security system really only cares about the UserInterface and does not worry about anything else the user might have.  Hence we have:

```
class AbstractController {
   protected function getUser(): ?UserInterface {
```

A bit off-topic but I am looking forward to the day when this bit of annotation is no longer needed and replace with something like:

```
    User $user = $this->getUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to get your current user, please try this one:

```
$creditCard= new creditCard();
$creditCard->setUser($this->getUser());
```

Or this one:

```
$creditCard= $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```